# how to get JQuery popup dialog url

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a web page called `Main.aspx` and in that I am calling a JQuery pop-up dialog and from here it goes to another pop-up dialog. My problem here is, when I retrieve `window.location.href` inside the pop-up, it is getting `Main.aspx` as the page url instead of pop-up dialog url. Can someone help me on this? I need to retrieve few params from these dialogs.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense, assuming you are setting the html contents of your popups using jQuery's `.load()` you should already have access to the url of the page they are displaying.

Comment: True..Sorry I forgot that I can access parent window elements with document.getElementById(); it worked. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

True..Sorry I forgot that I can access parent window elements with document.getElementById(); it worked. Thanks anyways.